# Resize slider with javascript

Tags: javascript, header, height

Current code:

```
cover_height: function() {

        if (!$('.typology-cover-empty').length) {

            var cover_height = $(window).height() - this.settings.admin_bar_height + Math.abs(parseInt($('.typology-section:first').css('top'), 10));
            var cover_content_height = $('.cover-item-container').height();
            var header_height = $('#typology-header').height();
            var cover_auto = true;

            if (cover_height < 450) {
                cover_height = 450;
            }

            if (cover_content_height > cover_height - header_height) {
                cover_height = cover_content_height + header_height + 100;
                cover_auto = false;
            }


            if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {

                this.settings.cover_height = cover_height;
                $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', cover_height);
                $('.typology-cover').css('height', cover_height);

            } else {
                $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());
                $('.typology-cover').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());
                this.settings.cover_height = $('.typology-cover').height();
            }

            if (cover_auto) {
                if (!$('.typology-cover-slider').length) {
                    $('.typology-cover-item').css('position', 'fixed');
                } else {
                    $('.typology-slider-wrapper-fixed').css('position', 'fixed');
                }
            }

        }
    },
```

What do I have to change in order to decrease the height of the slider? 
If you go to the website you will see its really big. 
The website is *Censored* and basically this resizes resizes based on the code above. But I'd like to make it smaller.

Comment: Are you only interested in reducing the height via Javascript, or CSS as well?

Comment: I'd like to resize it over Javascript by changing some stuff in code above if possible. 
If not then il just remove the javascript code and do CSS myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sliders height is computed by this script. The calculation depend on the windows height and the height of the sliders content. I dont think its a good idea to set a fix heigth of the slider. If you do so you will lose the sliders responsive abilities.

Here is were the sliders height is set:

```
    if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {

        this.settings.cover_height = cover_height;// this variable contains the calculated height if the windows width is lower than 1366
        $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', cover_height);// Here the sliders Elements are set to the calculated height if the windows width is lower than 1366
        $('.typology-cover').css('height', cover_height);// Here the sliders Elements are set to the calculated height if the windows width is lower than 1366

    } else {
        $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());// if windows width is greater than 1366 sliders Elements are set to its "natural height"
        $('.typology-cover').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());
        this.settings.cover_height = $('.typology-cover').height();// if windows width is greater than 1366 sliders Elements are set to its "natural height"
    }
```

You can do something like this to reduce the height:

```
    var reduceHeightValue = 50;
    if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {

        this.settings.cover_height = cover_height - reduceHeightValue;// reduce the height by 50 if windows width is lower than 1366
        $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', cover_height);// Here the sliders Elements are set to the calculated height if the windows width is lower than 1366
        $('.typology-cover').css('height', cover_height);// Here the sliders Elements are set to the calculated height if the windows width is lower than 1366

    } else {
        $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height() - reduceHeightValue);// reduce the height by 50 if windows width is greater than 1366
        $('.typology-cover').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height() - reduceHeightValue);// reduce the height by 50 if windows width is greater than 1366
        this.settings.cover_height = $('.typology-cover').height() - reduceHeightValue;// reduce the height by 50 if windows width is greater than 1366
    }
```

This kind of hacks can work for you, but most the time its not a good idea to change existing code this way because it will break something. 
Obviously there are settings for this slider where a height can be set. I recommend to use this settings. Read the documentation of the slider and set the height in a appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cover_height: function() {

    if (!$('.typology-cover-empty').length) {

        var cover_height = $(window).height() - this.settings.admin_bar_height + Math.abs(parseInt($('.typology-section:first').css('top'), 10));
        var cover_content_height = $('.cover-item-container').height();

        $('#typology-header').height(150);// Set the height in pixel
        var header_height = $('#typology-header').height();
        var cover_auto = true;

        if (cover_height < 450) {
            cover_height = 450;
        }

        if (cover_content_height > cover_height - header_height) {
            cover_height = cover_content_height + header_height + 100;
            cover_auto = false;
        }


        if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {

            this.settings.cover_height = cover_height;
            $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', cover_height);
            $('.typology-cover').css('height', cover_height);

        } else {
            $('.typology-cover-item').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());
            $('.typology-cover').css('height', $('.typology-cover').height());
            this.settings.cover_height = $('.typology-cover').height();
        }

        if (cover_auto) {
            if (!$('.typology-cover-slider').length) {
                $('.typology-cover-item').css('position', 'fixed');
            } else {
                $('.typology-slider-wrapper-fixed').css('position', 'fixed');
            }
        }

    }
},
```

Comment: Yea this increases the header size abit but the slider is still huge. That was my issue maybe I haven't explained well.

Comment: so change the value to a height that fits your needs
   $('#typology-header').height(150);// Set the height in pixel

Comment: Yep I understand that part but this changes the header. I need to fix the slider below this header. 
Increasing the header makes it slider look little bit smaller but its not that noticable.

Comment: Here is some slider code aswell maybe something here can be changed?https://pastebin.com/AAKG8V2x